# Do native speakers use "elegante?"

Tags: uso-de-palabras

I'm using Duolingo to learn Spanish. One of the first words that it taught me was "elegante." I'd consider this a quirk of Duolingo, but when I learned French in high school "élégant" was also a fairly early vocab word.

Do native Spanish speakers say "elegante" often or at least more than native English speakers say "elegant?" In English, outside of certain contexts (an "elegant" math proof), the word is used sparingly and, more often than not, ironically. When would it be appropriate to use "elegante" in Spanish?

Comment: For what its worth, as a native English speaker and fluent Spanish speaker, I don't see that _elegant_ is rare or special in English. I certainly wouldn't assume it is being used ironically. It is a perfectly common word, what makes you think it's rare in English?

Comment: I would say that "smart" is often used in English with this meaning. At the workplace.stackexchange they often advise to dress smart at interviews, where in Spanish they could have advised to "ir elegante" (o "ir bien vestido").

Comment: @Pere Perhaps that's the case in certain regions? I've heard *smart* used that way in British English a lot, and I think in Australian, but never in American English. In any case, I think that's the right approach here-- being a cognate is a poor guide to word use in another language (cue stories about *embarazada*...)

Comment: I was also thrown for a loop when Duolingo taught me "elegante" so early on.  It's almost never used in english except as programmer jargon or describing high-society (effeminate) dress/decor.  I did get some laughs at all the repetition of "Mi padre es elegante", imagining my dad was Elton John.

Comment: The word elegant is used in al varieties of English. "smart" meaning elegant is British English. If people would just take their heads out of programming, and do some real reading, they will see it is basically all over the place. As in better magazines, for example. An elegant room=a formal room that is well decorated.

Comment: As a native English speaker, "elegant" is not commonly used unless in relation to fashion, designers, or high quality clothing. To call a man elegant could be considered by some men to be an insult (an affront to masculinity). To call a woman elegant is not common but very much a complement. This is why the Spanish "elegante" seems strange to an English speaker.

Comment: @user32264 That is your opinion. It's a matter of expression. Obviously, lower class people don't go around saying elegant. However, they have some very colorful phrases.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know about native English speakers' use of **elegant**, but we Spaniards use **elegante** pretty much. It's a common word, mostly used in relation to dressing but also used in the science fields in the sense that you pointed.

According to the [DRAE](https://dle.rae.es/elegante):

> **elegante**
> 3. adj. Dicho de una persona: Que tiene buen gusto y distinción para vestir

For example, when you put **extra care in dressing** because you have a party, a wedding, or an official reception, if someone wants to give you a compliment, he/she probably would said:

> ¡Qué **elegante**!

I'm not sure about the exact translation in English but it probably is:

> What a **fancy** suit/dress!

or

> Wow, look at you, how **handsome**!

Comment: If It really functions like the English "fancy" then I can see it being an important vocabulary word. While "elegant" is seldom used in english, "fancy," "sharp," and "nice" are used frequently to describe a person's dress. Outside the scope of the question, but are there other words than "elegante" that are frequently used to describe dress in Spanish?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins I think that "elegante" is the most universal word in Spanish speaking contries. There is a lot of ways of saying it depending on the region or the country. For example, I think that in Mexico you could say: ¡Qué chido! (I'm from Spain, I'm not 100% sure). You should ask a different question to get more regionalisms or variants. :-)

Comment: Somebody called my shoes dapper recently. It was a person of the older generation admittedly.

Comment: Since when is *elegant* seldom used in English?

Comment: @nopaltepec Maybe you should address Charles with the @

Answer (score 1):

There is no English word with the same meaning as `elegante` used in Spanish. Here, -as the definition implies, it means a person of good taste and demeanor, not necessarily limited to the clothes he/she is wearing, but extending to the effect the person has on others. "Que elegante estás" means that the person is dressed tastefully and that his/her demeanor is such as to provide a feeling of satisfaction of being in that company or setting. "Que fiesta tan elegante" means what a fine and distinguished affair. `Fancy` or `handsome` do not capture the complete meaning of the word as used in the spanish language.

Comment: I'm Mexican, and I have never seen such usage. So, I'm guessing that it's a regional thing.

Comment: You said there's no English word with that meaning, but it really sounds like "classy" would fit the bill nicely.

Comment: I disagree - in English the word `elegant` means the same (in at least one context).  as @URL mentioned, this additional meaning might be a regional thing.

Answer (score 1):

I was curious as well. Duolingo uses this particular word frequently. Every lesson has a sentence using it. Which seems to imply it is used often. There are other descriptive words for nice clothes and attractive people, duo is just giving you one word to begin with for learning purposes.

Comment: Welcome to [spanish.se]! Note, the [tour] and [help] sections give a helpful introduction to the [se] approach. A well written answer focuses on exactly what's being asked, contributes something new that hasn't appeared in an answer yet, and is documented with sources, logic, or usage examples. If you have something less well developed to contribute, when you have enough reputation (50) please use the comment box. The best way to show your agreement with an existing answer is to upvote it!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, in beginning Spanish, Duo Lingo tries to use some words that resemble english words, to facilitate fast learning. Elegante, teléfono, supermercado: elegant, telephone, supermarket, and so on. It allows one to see noun placement, verb placement, adjective placement, etc., by using easily identifiable words so as not to muddy the water so to speak.  And, I agree that the word elegant is NOT used much in english conversation today, but we all know what it means.

Comment: The OP wanted to know if it is used frequently in Spanish. Are saying it is not and that Duolingo overuses it?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/25758)